# Mapping over fields from a string value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a strange use case for how I map fields for an object. FWIW, I am using `v-for` over the data (`Vue.js`)

For example,

`<div> {{ item['foo'] }} </div>` works fine ✅

`<div> {{ item['foo.bar'] }} </div>` renders nothing ❌

`<div> {{ item['foo.bar[0].baz'] }} </div>` renders nothing ❌

I tried to use regex to convert it

`<div> {{ 'item[foo.bar]'.match(/([\w\.]+)/g).join('.') }} </div>` which just rendered the string itself.

How do I correctly do the following get `{{ item['foo.bar'] }}` to work the same as `{{ item.foo.bar'] }}`

Comment: Can you provide code snippet?

Comment: When you do `item['foo.bar']`, this assume there is an item named `'foo.bar'`. If not, with the `dot` notation it should be `item.foo.bar`, and `bracket` notation should be `item['foo']['bar']` ..... or what am I missing here?

Comment: Yes there is an item there named 'foo.bar'. I know the annotation needs to be `item['foo']['bar]` but how do I get my string to be that syntax?

Comment: So you get this string, `item['foo.bar']` from elsewhere, and need to do a conversion to `item.foo.bar` programmatically?

Comment: Correct- I need to convert `item['foo.bar']` to `item.foo.bar` programmatically

Comment: Okay, so when doing like that, you'll need to use `eval()` or similar to _objectify_ it, or else it will only return the string, though `eval()` can be/is evil and should be used with extreme care. Will this work ? `<div> {{ eval('item[foo.bar]'.match(/([\w\.]+)/g).join('.')) }} </div>`

Comment: It does not work- it tells me `Property or method "eval" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive`

Comment: Since eval is window method, during render phase, its undefined

Comment: Yes I tried that- but it told me `Property or method "window" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render` then `Cannot read property 'eval' of undefined"`

Comment: you can try creating a method, then do your matching and parsing on there. It won't cause this issue i believe. Also i recommend you to write a simple recursive function, which looking up till you find that key map

Comment: @Tugayİlik I tried creating a method too- which rendered `function () { [native code] }`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, works nicely

My object looks like this:

```
{ foo: { bar: 23 } }
```

In my render:

```
<div> {{ formatResult(item, 'foo.bar') }} </div>
```

With method to do the following:

```
formatResults(item, fields){
    return fields.split(".").reduce((a, b) => a[b], item)
    // this returns 23
}
```